# How to extract subtitles from .wtv file using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, dvb

does anyone know how to extract subtitles from a wtv file using ffmpeg?
i have tried many different commands. None of them works.
the closest is this one

```
ffmpeg -i input.wtv -vn -an -codec:s:0 srt test.srt
```

But it complains Error while encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height

what does that really mean??

The complete console output is as follows

```
ffmpeg version N-52233-gee94362 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Apr 18 2013 02:50:33 with gcc 4.8.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
  libavutil      52. 26.100 / 52. 26.100
  libavcodec     55.  2.100 / 55.  2.100
  libavformat    55.  2.100 / 55.  2.100
  libavdevice    55.  0.100 / 55.  0.100
  libavfilter     3. 56.103 /  3. 56.103
  libswscale      2.  2.100 /  2.  2.100
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
[wtv @ 0269bac0] truncated file
    Last message repeated 3 times
[mpeg2video @ 02692f60] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
    Last message repeated 12 times
[wtv @ 0269bac0] max_analyze_duration 5000000 reached at 5016000 microseconds
Input #0, wtv, from '16 and Pregnant- Unseen Moments_Viva_2013_04_09_19_57_00.wtv':
  Metadata:
    WM/MediaClassPrimaryID: db9830bd-3ab3-4fab-8a371a995f7ff74
    WM/MediaClassSecondaryID: ba7f258a-62f7-47a9-b21f4651c42a000
    Title           : 16 and Pregnant: Unseen Moments
    WM/SubTitleDescription: Dr Drew hosts a look at the exclusive moments we didn't see from the second season of 16 and Pregnant.
    genre           : Documentary;Reality TV
    WM/OriginalReleaseTime: 0
    WM/MediaCredits : ;;;
    service_provider: Viva
    service_name    : Viva
    WM/MediaOriginalChannel: 16
    WM/MediaOriginalChannelSubNumber: 0
    WM/MediaOriginalBroadcastDateTime: 2011-12-13T00:00:00Z
    WM/MediaOriginalRunTime: 38377217299
    WM/MediaIsStereo: false
    WM/MediaIsRepeat: true
    WM/MediaIsLive  : false
    WM/MediaIsTape  : false
    WM/MediaIsDelay : false
    WM/MediaIsSubtitled: false
    WM/MediaIsMovie : false
    WM/MediaIsPremiere: false
    WM/MediaIsFinale: false
    WM/MediaIsSAP   : false
    WM/MediaIsSport : false
    WM/Provider     : MediaCenterDefault
    WM/VideoClosedCaptioning: false
    WM/WMRVEncodeTime: 2013-04-09 18:57:02
    WM/WMRVSeriesUID: !GenericSeries!16 and Pregnant: Unseen Moments
    WM/WMRVServiceID: !Generated!be3ff88ee57a4cadb0334ef3df5bc91b
    WM/WMRVProgramID: !MCProgram!37282063
    WM/WMRVRequestID: 0
    WM/WMRVScheduleItemID: 0
    WM/WMRVQuality  : 0
    WM/WMRVOriginalSoftPrePadding: 480
    WM/WMRVOriginalSoftPostPadding: 60
    WM/WMRVHardPrePadding: -300
    WM/WMRVHardPostPadding: 0
    WM/WMRVATSCContent: false
    WM/WMRVDTVContent: true
    WM/WMRVHDContent: false
    Duration        : 38379654765
    WM/WMRVEndTime  : 2013-04-09 20:01:00
    WM/WMRVBitrate  : 2.118481
    WM/WMRVKeepUntil: 0
    WM/WMRVActualSoftPrePadding: 477
    WM/WMRVActualSoftPostPadding: 60
    WM/WMRVContentProtected: false
    WM/WMRVContentProtectedPercent: 0
    WM/WMRVExpirationSpan: 9223372036854775807
    WM/WMRVInBandRatingSystem: 255
    WM/WMRVInBandRatingLevel: 255
    WM/WMRVInBandRatingAttributes: 0
    WM/WMRVWatched  : true
  Duration: 01:03:58.07, start: 1.509175, bitrate: 2118 kb/s
    Stream #0:0[0x22](eng): Subtitle: dvb_subtitle
    Stream #0:1[0x23](eng): Audio: mp2 (P[0][0][0] / 0x0050), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 256 kb/s
    Stream #0:2[0x24]: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p, 544x576 [SAR 32:17 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 10000k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:3[0x0]: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p, 189x200 [SAR 96:96 DAR 189:200], 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
    Metadata:
      title           : TV Thumbnail
File 'test.srt' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] Output #0, srt, to 'test.srt':
  Metadata:
    WM/MediaClassPrimaryID: db9830bd-3ab3-4fab-8a371a995f7ff74
    WM/MediaClassSecondaryID: ba7f258a-62f7-47a9-b21f4651c42a000
    Title           : 16 and Pregnant: Unseen Moments
    WM/SubTitleDescription: Dr Drew hosts a look at the exclusive moments we didn't see from the second season of 16 and Pregnant.
    genre           : Documentary;Reality TV
    WM/OriginalReleaseTime: 0
    WM/MediaCredits : ;;;
    service_provider: Viva
    service_name    : Viva
    WM/MediaOriginalChannel: 16
    WM/MediaOriginalChannelSubNumber: 0
    WM/MediaOriginalBroadcastDateTime: 2011-12-13T00:00:00Z
    WM/MediaOriginalRunTime: 38377217299
    WM/MediaIsStereo: false
    WM/MediaIsRepeat: true
    WM/MediaIsLive  : false
    WM/MediaIsTape  : false
    WM/MediaIsDelay : false
    WM/MediaIsSubtitled: false
    WM/MediaIsMovie : false
    WM/MediaIsPremiere: false
    WM/MediaIsFinale: false
    WM/MediaIsSAP   : false
    WM/MediaIsSport : false
    WM/Provider     : MediaCenterDefault
    WM/VideoClosedCaptioning: false
    WM/WMRVEncodeTime: 2013-04-09 18:57:02
    WM/WMRVSeriesUID: !GenericSeries!16 and Pregnant: Unseen Moments
    WM/WMRVServiceID: !Generated!be3ff88ee57a4cadb0334ef3df5bc91b
    WM/WMRVProgramID: !MCProgram!37282063
    WM/WMRVRequestID: 0
    WM/WMRVScheduleItemID: 0
    WM/WMRVQuality  : 0
    WM/WMRVOriginalSoftPrePadding: 480
    WM/WMRVOriginalSoftPostPadding: 60
    WM/WMRVHardPrePadding: -300
    WM/WMRVHardPostPadding: 0
    WM/WMRVATSCContent: false
    WM/WMRVDTVContent: true
    WM/WMRVHDContent: false
    Duration        : 38379654765
    WM/WMRVEndTime  : 2013-04-09 20:01:00
    WM/WMRVBitrate  : 2.118481
    WM/WMRVKeepUntil: 0
    WM/WMRVActualSoftPrePadding: 477
    WM/WMRVActualSoftPostPadding: 60
    WM/WMRVContentProtected: false
    WM/WMRVContentProtectedPercent: 0
    WM/WMRVExpirationSpan: 9223372036854775807
    WM/WMRVInBandRatingSystem: 255
    WM/WMRVInBandRatingLevel: 255
    WM/WMRVInBandRatingAttributes: 0
    WM/WMRVWatched  : true
    Stream #0:0(eng): Subtitle: srt
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (dvbsub -> srt)
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

Comment: Please include the complete ffmpeg console output that results after you enter your ffmpeg command.

Comment: Thanks for responding
where should I look?